# Como fazer scroll infinito com javascript puro?

Tags: javascript, rolamento

Estou tentando implementar um scroll infinito no meu site, como **[este aqui](http://wandaprint.com/home/)**, porém estou com dificuldades para fazer o script que pega o evento de rolagem do mouse. Tentei usar esse script (abaixo) que peguei em um site, mas ele não é exatamente o que preciso. Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

```
cont=0
function handle(delta) {
    var nav = document.getElementById('navegacao');
    var ln = nav.getElementsByTagName('a');
    if (delta < 0){
        cont=cont+1;
        ln[cont].click();
    }
    else{
        cont=cont-1;
        ln[cont].click();
    }
}

function wheel(event){
    var delta = 0;
    if (!event) event = window.event;
    if (event.wheelDelta) {
        delta = event.wheelDelta/120; 
    } else if (event.detail) {
        delta = -event.detail/3;
    }
    if (delta)
        handle(delta);
        if (event.preventDefault)
                event.preventDefault();
        event.returnValue = false;
}

/* Initialization code. */
if (window.addEventListener)
    window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;
```

Comment: O que esse código faz que você não gosta? O que exatamente você precisa fazer?

Comment: Então @bfavaretto eu preciso que quando eu realize a rolagem do mouse passe para o próximo elemento da minha página tipo assim: http://wandaprint.com/home porém esse código (que postei e foi o único que encontrei), pula de dois em dois elementos Oo

Comment: Esse site aí não passa no PageSpeed: o preloader dele está perto dos 20% aqui já faz quase um minuto.

Comment: hahahaha @GustavoRodrigues Realmente é um site muito pesado, tem muitas imagens, mas é um site bem feito (a parte de design pelo menos rs)

Comment: Ainda espero que o PageSpeed popularize, ainda mais aqui no Brasil onde as velocidades não são tão altas. Espero que ele termine de carregar para eu poder comentar sobre ele.

Comment: A página carregou! Essa página não precisa tanto de um preloader para as imagens. Organize os elementos primeiro então carregue as imagens conforme o usuário vai navegando pelas imagens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOMMouseScroll só funciona no Firefox, você também tem que usar onmousescroll para funcionar em outros browsers. Fiz um exemplo de paginação com scroll como a do link que você postou no jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c6PPv/3/

Comment: não funcionou no Chrome.

Comment: Exatamente, testei aqui e nada aconteceu @PauloRoberto

Comment: @PauloRoberto consegui alguma coisa http://jsbin.com/kozukizi/2/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: ainda não é o que você queria @Odair?

Comment: Sim, é exatamente isso, porém eu queria fazer a chamada no meu javascript e não na div como fiz, você sabe se tem essa possibilidade @PauloRoberto?

Comment: o que você quer dizer com isto @Odair ? eu não pude entender, pode explicar melhor?

Comment: Desculpa @PauloRoberto, estou começando a programar agora hehehe então no caso eu fiz a chamada da minha função na div <divclass="box" id="janela-home" onMouseWheel="Picture()"></div>, tem como eu chamar ela no script? alguma coisa como window.onMouseWheel...

Comment: veja minha resposta @Odair

Comment: Atualizei o link na resposta, funcionando no Chrome.

Comment: Muito obrigado @Wynn :)

Answer (score 1):

De maneira genérica para fazer uma página de scroll infinito é [mais ou menos assim](https://gist.github.com/qgustavor/9211594), mas no caso o que você quer é fazer tipo uma paralaxe.

Assim como no exemplo do scroll infinito o que você pode fazer é evitar que eventos sucessivos sejam processados, logo use um timeout:

```
var scrolling;
function wheel () {
  if (scrolling) {return;}

  scrolling = true;
  setTimeout(function () {
    scrolling = false;
  }, 200 /* o tempo para animar a página */);

  /* o resto da função */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Com o código que desenvolvestes [aqui](http://jsbin.com/kozukizi/3/edit) que seria:

```
var count=0;
function Picture(){
    if (event.wheelDelta >= 4){
        if(count == 3){
            count=-1;
        }else{
            Resize(++count);
        }
    }
    else if (event.wheelDelta <= 4)
        if(count == 0){
            count=4;
        }else{
            Resize(--count);
        }
    return false;
}
function Resize(c){    
    var nav = document.getElementById('navegacao');
    var btn = nav.getElementsByTagName('li');
    var ln = nav.getElementsByTagName('a');
    ln[c].click();
}
```

Utilizando a chamada direto no `<div>` do seu html:

```
<divclass="box" id="janela-home" onMouseWheel="Picture()"></div>
```

Você gostaria de chamar no js para que ela execute no window, por isso deves remover este evento `onMouseWheel` do html e utilizar o seguinte código:

```
var mousewheelevt=(/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent))? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel" //Firefox não reconhece o mouseWheel na versão FF3.x

if (document.attachEvent) //para IE (e Opera dependendo das configurações do usuário)
    document.attachEvent("on"+mousewheelevt, function(e){Picture()})
else if (document.addEventListener) //WC3 browsers
    document.addEventListener(mousewheelevt, function(e){Picture()}, false);
```

## [Referência](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/onmousewheel.shtml)

Comment: Muito obrigado @PauloRoberto! Funcionou certinho!